# Is os.path.expanduser("~/x") equivalent to os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser("~/x"))?

Tags: python, path, cross-platform, absolute-path

In Python, can I be sure the expanded user call will be an absolute path if the path has "~" in it?

For example, is this expression always true?

```
path = '~/.my_app'
os.path.expanduser(path) == os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(path))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what your `$HOME` points to. On most properly set-up systems (every mainstream Linux distro, OSX and Windows) it'll point to an absolute path, e.g. `/home/user` or `C:/Users/User`. But if it's unset, improperly set or even changed manually (`export HOME=.`), `expanduser` may result in a relative path, in which case `abspath` will further change it.

But for most intents and purposes, you can assume that yes, both expressions are equivalent.